# Multiprocessing is too slow in multiple loops in Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, multithreading, parallel-processing, multiprocessing

I am trying to convert a multiple loop function into a multiprocessing function to take advantage of multiprocessing.

The initial code looks like this:

```
from tqdm import tqdm 
import re
import re, string

def transform_data(sentence, aug):
    # some processing from different module function
    out = [re.sub('[%s]' % re.escape(string.punctuation), '', k) for k in sentence]
    return out
    



def bulk_aug(final_df_num):
    
    final_aug_data = []
    
    for data_keys in tqdm(final_df_num):
    
        aug_data   = []
        random_key = data_keys['key']
        sentences  = data_keys['data']

        for chunked_sentence in tqdm(sentences):
            ug_d = transform_data(chunked_sentence, 2)
            aug_data.append(ug_d)
        
        print(aug_data)
        final_aug_data.append({'key': random_key, 
                           'data': [" ".join(k) for k in list(zip(*aug_data))]})
    return final_aug_data
```

The data looks like this:

```
data = [{'key': 12, 'data': [['this is a ?sentence1', 'this is a sentence1'], ['this is a sentence2', 'this is a sentence2'], 
                             ['this is a sentence3', 'this is a sentence3'], ['this is a sentence4', 'this is a sentence4']]},
        
        {'key': 190, 'data': [['this is a sentence11', 'this is a sentence11'], ['this is a sentence22', 'this is a sentence22'], 
                             ['this is a sentence33', 'this is a sentence33'], ['this is a sentence44', 'this is a sentence44']]}, 
        
        {'key': 1900, 'data': [['this is a sentence55', 'this is a sentence55'], ['this is a sentence66', 'this is a sentence66'], 
                              ['this is a sentence77', 'this is a sentence77'], ['this is a sentence88', 'this is a sentence88']]}]
```

and the output looks like this:

```
# bulk_aug(data)


[{'key': 12,
  'data': ['this is a sentence1 this is a sentence2 this is a sentence3 this is a sentence4',
   'this is a sentence1 this is a sentence2 this is a sentence3 this is a sentence4']},
 {'key': 190,
  'data': ['this is a sentence11 this is a sentence22 this is a sentence33 this is a sentence44',
   'this is a sentence11 this is a sentence22 this is a sentence33 this is a sentence44']},
 {'key': 1900,
  'data': ['this is a sentence55 this is a sentence66 this is a sentence77 this is a sentence88',
   'this is a sentence55 this is a sentence66 this is a sentence77 this is a sentence88']}]
```

I want to convert this function into a multiprocessing function. What I tried:

```
def bulk_aug(final_df_num):
    
    final_aug_data = []
    aug_data       = []
        
    data_keys  = final_df_num
    random_key = data_keys['key']
    sentences  = data_keys['data']

    for chunked_sentence in tqdm(sentences):
        ug_d = transform_data(chunked_sentence, 2)
        aug_data.append(ug_d)
        
        print(aug_data)
        
    final_aug_data.append({'key': random_key, 
                       'data': [" ".join(k) for k in list(zip(*aug_data))]})
    return final_aug_data

from multiprocessing import Pool
import time


with Pool(2) as p:
    r = list(tqdm(p.imap(bulk_aug, data), total=len(data)))
```

But it's taking too much time to process the data. Is there something wrong with the code?

Comment: Are you sure this is due to the computation time and not the overhead of the IPC in the `imap`?

Comment: Are you sure that you posted the actual code you are running with? Your serial code is not complete and your multiprocessing code generates a **TypeError: string indices must be integers** error (as would your serial code).

Answer (score 0):

I can't test the speed of my code without a large amount of data, since the overhead of creating new processes is large.

The idea behind the original code is right, but a lot of time is used transferring the data (pickling/unpickling) to and from new processes.

Here is a version passing the data in chunks, so there is a little less overhead communicating with the process.

```
def simple_aug(data_keys):
    aug_data   = []
    random_key = data_keys['key']
    sentences  = data_keys['data']

    for chunked_sentence in sentences:
        ug_d = transform_data(chunked_sentence, 2)
        aug_data.append(ug_d)
    
    # print(aug_data)
    return {'key': random_key, 
                       'data': [" ".join(k) for k in list(zip(*aug_data))]}

def bulk_aug_mp(final_df_num, nproc=2):
    with Pool(nproc) as p:
        rv = p.map(simple_aug, final_df_num, chunksize=(len(final_df_num)//nproc)+1)
    return list(rv)
```

In Linux, you can do a little better if `data` is a global variable and you do not change it during processing:

```
def bulk_aug_chunks(idx_init, idx_end):
    global data
    final_aug_data = []
    for data_keys in data[idx_init:idx_end]:
        aug_data   = []
        random_key = data_keys['key']
        sentences  = data_keys['data']

        for chunked_sentence in sentences:
            ug_d = transform_data(chunked_sentence, 2)
            aug_data.append(ug_d)
        
        # print(aug_data)
        final_aug_data.append({'key': random_key, 
                           'data': [" ".join(k) for k in list(zip(*aug_data))]})
    return final_aug_data

def bulk_aug_mp2(final_df_num, nproc=2):
    chunk_size = len(final_df_num)//nproc
    ends = [chunk_size * (_+1)  for _ in range(nproc)]
    ends[-1] += len(final_df_num) % nproc
    starts = [chunk_size * _  for _ in range(nproc)]
    with Pool(nproc) as p:
        rv = p.starmap(bulk_aug_chunks, zip(starts, ends))
    return [r for sublist in rv for r in sublist]
```